# After submission of form, how to get the user_input printed at the same page of the form in html?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, fetch

With only JavaScript, how can the submitted information be displayed at the bottom of the same html page below the form? Does this have anything to do with ajax or fetch? Is it something just can be done in html?

```
<form>
<div type = "input" name = "address"></div>
<div type = "input" name = "email"></div>
</form>
<div type = "submit" name = "submit"></div>
```

After submit this form, how do I get the address and email printed at the same page of the form?

> The webpage should look like this:

```
===================================
|                                 |
|                                 |
|    FORM Needs to be submitted|
|                                 |
|                                  |
|====================================
_________
|BUTTON|
________

Display the addr and email here:
addr:
email:
```

Comment: no, the fetch works the other way around. but anyway your question is too vague

Comment: What does it mean work the other way around? I have a form and a submit button below that form. How to display the submitted form data below that form in the same page? Is this something like infinite scrolling?

Comment: a fetch is used to obtain information from a server: the downward flow